# Source of WSO2 Identity Server Service Pack

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Is the source of service pack 1 for  WSO2 Identity Server 5.0.0 publicly available?
Where can I find the source in the SVN repository?

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any source code for Service Pack.

A Service pack is generated by aggregating patches provided for a product in WSO2.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the README  file of service pack 1 the patches are listed (e.g. WSO2-CARBON-PATCH-4.2.0-0621). But for me it is unclear how to build exactly the needed patch. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Service pack contains the patches which addresses the identified defects. So it's advice to apply the service pack as a whole. Patch itself contains the bundles + configurations which need to be done in order to correct the defect. So there is no way of building the patch if you not know the exact fix done. If you know the fix done then you can apply it to the release tag and build the jars where you can put it inside the patches directory to apply.

Comment: Thanks again.  I understand that it makes sense to apply the patch as a whole. Unfortunately we had to patch identity server by ourselves to work around some bugs. The sources of the service pack would be helpful to merge our own fixes into the code.